# How to show pipeline on Gitlab-managed Terraform state UI?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am trying out [Gitlab-managed Terraform state](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html#manage-terraform-state-files), I managed to deploy my infrastructure with Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, but the UI is not showing the pipeline that deployed the infrastructure.

[image: Gitlab-managed Terraform state UI that does not have pipeline shown]

I also enable deployment environment by the `environment` keyword

[image: Environment UI showing pipeline details]

I am running an on-premise installation of Gitlab at v15.8.0. I wrote my own `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Am I missing something in the pipeline that causes this bug?

I tried out the steps as described in the [official documentation on Terraform MR integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html). It worked as intended, but it is not relevent to the managed Terraform state UI.

Answer (score 0):

Since i'm using the "TF_PASSWORD" variables, I no more have the "pipeline references" on the Terraform state UI.

There is no clean solution, using the TF_PASSWORD let your team been able to deploy and update the terraform state. Otherwise, you must keep the deployment process for someone who has the "maintainer" role on your project (and then you will recover the pipeline references)

The "TF_PASSWORD" let you by-pass the "permission elevation", in order to manage the terraform state